# Adding margin to font awesome icon in React

Tags: css, reactjs, reactstrap, font-awesome-5

I use **reactstrap** in my project. I tried to add a margin to the font awesome icon in my react project, but it didn't work.

What am I missing?

```
<NavItem>
     <NavLink active href="/products"><FontAwesomeIcon className="mr-2" icon={faClone}></FontAwesomeIcon><span>Products</span></NavLink>
</NavItem>
```

Answer (score 2):

className won't work on a component, it only works on DOM elements. Try wrapping FontAwesomeIcon in a div/span

```
<NavItem>
     <NavLink active href="/products"><div className="mr-2"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faClone}></FontAwesomeIcon><span>Products</span><div></NavLink>
</NavItem>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this has changed since you wrote your answer, but bootstrap styles definitely affect the `<FontAwesomeIcon />` components directly, I'm using the Reactstrap library right now and it works for me.  Whether or not it's the best thing to do is another matter entirely - my assumption is that Best option would be to use the API @Fortawesome provides, `transform={{ JS-style-tags here }}` - but I didn't want this hanging out there without rebutting, lest people get bad information from this site.

Answer (score 1):

I use the exact setup i-e *reactstrap* & *react-fontawesome* and this is what I use and it works perfect

```
<button>
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} className="mr-3" /> Add
</button>
```

PS: Note that `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faIcon} />` is a self closing tag, and i think this is were you are getting this wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Why you are using Font Awesome Icon component when you can use html code. Just simply add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

in index.js.